# Using an array as a map key is not working with C++ 11 compiler command?

Tags: c++

I need to use an array as the map key, but I receive compiler errors indicating that the map declaration does not name a type.

I use the code in a similar question, but the code does not compile even when I have chosen the -std=c++0x or -std=c++11 compiler commands.

The code I used is:

```
typedef std::array<unsigned int, 3> alphabet;

std::map<alphabet, std::string> dictionary;

dictionary[{{1, 0, 8}}] = "hello";
```

The error is:

> error: 'dictionary' does not name a type| error: expected
>   unqualified-id before ']' token| ||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 0
>   warnings (0 minutes, 1 seconds) ===|

I see little on this topic even when searching Google. I am using CodeBlocks as my IDE and chosen the compiler commands mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error may be because you're trying to assign to `dictionary` in file scope. As pointed out, variables should be initialized in global scope, i.e.:

```
std::map<alphabet, std::string> dictionary = { {{1,0,8}, "hello"} };
```

Otherwise, you should put it in block scope, i.e. in a `main()`.

```
#include <array>
#include <map>

typedef std::array<unsigned int, 3> alphabet;

std::map<alphabet, std::string> dictionary;

int main()
{
  dictionary[{{1, 0, 8}}] = "hello";
}
```

As a side note, it seems that the braces can be elided. You do not need two sets of braces. `dictionary[{1, 0, 8}]` will suffice.

Comment: Or use an initializer : `std::map<alphabet, std::string> dictionary { {{1,0,8}, "hello"} };`

Comment: Thank you. My final goal is to perform this operation within a class. I was testing it outside the main() function. This works, but I am not sure how to implement this in a class.

Comment: @user3171630 You will get the same error. Just initialize it, or place the assignment inside a function, i.e. a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

How you compare the arrays for the map sort?

I guess you should supply compare method like this:

```
struct ltarray
{
  bool operator()(const alphabet& s1, const alphabet& s2) const
  {
    //how you compare???
    return (s1<s2);
  }
};
```

and you need to init your map template with the compare method:

```
std::map<alphabet, std::string, ltarray> dictionary;
```